# JS Calculator giving wrong answer

Tags: javascript, calculator

Ok so I made a simple calculator in JS and when I type the numbers and click on Submit then the wrong answer is returned. What am I doing wrong? The calculator is avaliable here: https://cdvcalc.github.io/

This bug fixing would be the last step to completing it.

Comment: is it hard to put the part of code where you are finding issues?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: And how we reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1):

**Note: You're being downvoted because you did not provide the code, and instead linked to it. In the future, provide a code snippet in your actual question (use the `<>` button in the editor).**

Code below pulled from linked page:

Your HTML elements have id's of `var1` and `var2`, but you reference `var1` for both numbers in your math operations.

Your HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <hr>
    <h1>DIVISION</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Type the first number here:</p>
    <input type="text" id="var1">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <p>Type the second number here:</p>
    <input type="text" id="var2">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <p>Result:</p>
    <p><button onclick="quo();" class="button button4">SUBMIT</button></p>
    <hr>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function quo(){
           var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('var1').value);
           var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById('var1').value);
           var c = a / b;
           document.write(c);
        };
    </script>
</div>
```

So this:

```
function quo(){
  var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('var1').value);
  var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById('var1').value);
  var c = a / b;
  document.write(c);
};
```

Should instead be:

```
function quo(){
  var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('var1').value);
  var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById('var2').value); // <--- var2 instead
  var c = a / b;
  document.write(c);
};
```

Comment: Silly me, little mistake screws it up big time! Thanks tho!:) Im only 17 and have absolutely no clue about SO but thanka for telling me!:)